# Docker - php_network_getaddresses error when trying to connect to DB

Tags: docker, laravel-5, docker-compose, dockerfile

Setting up a new Laravel install using docker, this is the docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
web:
    image: nginx
    restart: always
    links:
        - "fpm"
    volumes:
        - ./build/volumes/nginx/conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d:ro
    volumes_from:
        - fpm
    ports:
        - 8080:80

mysql:
    image: mysql
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "[OMMITTED]"
        MYSQL_DATABASE: "[OMMITTED]"
        MYSQL_USER: "[OMMITTED]"
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: "[OMMITTED]"

fpm:
    build:
        context: .
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www
```

`docker-compose up -d`  works fine and I can see the web sever at http://localhost:8080/ , however when trying to do any type of connection to the database, I get a `PDO::__construct(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known` error message.

My .env file contains the following ( the DB_HOST is the container name ):

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=container_mysql_1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=[OMMITTED]
DB_USERNAME=[OMMITTED]
DB_PASSWORD=[OMMITTED]
```

Attempted to use localhost as the DB_HOST however, it comes back with the `Access denied for user` error and i've checked that the details are correct. I'm assuming the docker containers are not talking to each other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You missed docker link:

```
fpm:
    build:
        context: .
    volumes:
        - .:/var/www
    links:
      - mysql:mysql
```

Comment: Works! Thank you :)